# What is the most general category in which isomorphisms theorems holds+

Tags: category-theory

The first isomorphism theorem for groups, rings, etc, is:

- $G/\text{ker}(f) \simeq im(f)$, for a morphism $f\colon G \rightarrow G'$ in the respective category.

What is the most general category in which we can do this?

Comment: Well, you'll need to first pick a reformulation of the first isomorphism theorem in purely categorical language (e.g. kernels, quotients, images are not immediately built into the category-theoretic language). One principle you might look at is **existence of unique epi-monic factorizations**: any morphism $f$ can be written as a composition $f=m\circ e$ with $e$ epic and $m$ monic *uniquely up to isomorphism*, the idea being that $e$ represents the surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $G/\ker(f)$ and $m$ the embedding of that quotient structure into the codomain.

Comment: Also relevant: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24755/reference-request-for-category-theory-works-which-quickly-prove-the-theorem-whic), [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair), [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/the-first-isomorphism-theorem-for-abelian-categories/), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765837/a-categorical-first-isomorphism-theorem).

Answer (score 5):

It turns out to be surprisingly tricky to define the image in an abstract category; the answer mostly depends on what you want the image to be.

The LHS is easier. In any category whatsoever we can ask for the [kernel pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair) of a morphism, which is a "nonlinear" generalization of the kernel. For a morphism $f : X \to Y$ you can think of it intuitively as the equivalence relation on $X$ given by $x_1 \sim x_2$ iff $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, and that's what it works out to be in familiar concrete examples. Then you can ask for the coequalizer of the kernel pair, which quotients $X$ by this equivalence relation; the result is called the [regular coimage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/image) $\text{coim}(f)$ of $f$.

There's a dual construction given by taking the equalizer of the [cokernel pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cokernel+pair) and it produces a construction called the regular image $\text{im}(f)$ of $f$. There is always a natural map $\text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f)$, which is always both a monomorphism and an epimorphism (sometimes called a [bimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bimorphism) although personally I don't like this term), but not always an isomorphism. I would say that a usable definition of "the first isomorphism theorem" in a generic category is that this map is an isomorphism.

Here are some examples of how these constructions behave in practice.

*Example.* In $\text{Set}$ both the regular coimage and regular image are the ordinary image of a function. This is not entirely trivial because they're computed in two different ways.

*Example.* In an abelian category the regular coimage can be computed as the cokernel of the kernel and the regular image can be computed as the kernel of the cokernel. It's a standard fact about abelian categories that these end up being equivalent, and define the "image," unambiguously, of a morphism in an abelian category.

*Example.* In $\text{Top}$ the regular coimage of a continuous function $f : X \to Y$ is the set-theoretic image of $f$ topologized as a quotient of $X$, and the regular image is the set-theoretic image of $f$ topologized as a subspace of $Y$. Thus the map $\text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f)$ is always a continuous bijection but the topologies may not agree, although they do if $X$ and $Y$ are both compact Hausdorff.

*Example.* In $\text{Ban}_1$, the category of Banach spaces and linear maps of norm at most $1$ (which has much better categorical properties than the usual $\text{Ban}$), the regular image of a continuous linear map $f : X \to Y$ is the set-theoretic image of $f$ with the quotient norm from $X$, and the regular coimage is the *closure* of the set-theoretic image of $f$ with the subspace norm from $Y$. So the map $\text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f)$ has dense set-theoretic image but may not be surjective and the norms may not agree.